# Why bc and args doesn't work together in one line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, bc

I need help using xargs(1) and bc(1) in the same line. I can do it multiple lines, but I really want to find a solution in one line.

Here is the problem: The following line will print the size of a `file.txt`

```
ls -l file.txt | cut -d" " -f5
```

And, the following line will print `1450` (which is obviously 1500 - 50)

```
echo '1500-50' | bc
```

Trying to add those two together, I do this:

```
ls -l file.txt | cut -d" " -f5 | xargs -0 -I {} echo '{}-50' | bc
```

The problem is, it's not working! :)

I know that xargs is probably not the right command to use, but it's the only command I can find who can let me decide where to put the argument I get from the pipe.

This is not the first  time I'm having issues with this kind of problem. It will be much of a help..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
ls -l file.txt | cut -d" " -f5 | xargs -0 -I {} echo '{}-50'
```

you will see this output:

```
23
-50
```

This means, that `bc` does not see a complete expression.

Just use `-n 1` instead of `-0`:

```
ls -l file.txt | cut -d" " -f5 | xargs -n 1 -I {} echo '{}-50'
```

and you get

```
23-50
```

which `bc` will process happily:

```
ls -l file.txt | cut -d" " -f5 | xargs -n 1 -I {} echo '{}-50' | bc
-27
```

So your basic problem is, that `-0` expects not lines but `\0` terminated strings. And hence the newline(s) of the previous commands in the pipe garble the expression of bc.

Comment: Better to know my mistakes then to get an alternative :)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
ls -l file.txt | cut -d" " -f5 | sed 's/.*/&-50/' | bc
```

Infact you could remove the cut:

```
ls -l file.txt | sed -r 's/^(\S+\s+){4}(\S+).*/\2-50/' | bc
```

Or use awk:

```
ls -l file.txt | awk '{print $5-50}'
```

Comment: Thanks man, Didn't know about the '&' replacement for a pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing output from the `ls` command is not the best idea. (really).

you can use many other solutions, like:

```
find . -name file.txt -printf "%s\n"
```

or

```
stat -c %s file.txt
```

or

```
wc -c <file.txt
```

and can use bash arithmetics, for avoid unnecessary slow process forks, like:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' name
do
        size=$(wc -c <$name)
        s50=$(( $size - 50 ))
        echo "the file=$name= size:$size minus 50 is: $s50"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, which only use one external command: `stat`:

```
file_size=$(stat -c "%s" file.txt) # Get the file size
let file_size=file_size-50         # Subtract 50
```

If you really want to combine them into one line:

```
let file_size=$(stat -c "%s" file.txt)-50
```

The `stat` command gets you the file size in bytes. The syntax above is for Linux (I tested against Ubuntu). On the Mac the syntax is a little different:

```
let file_size=$(stat -f "%z" mini.csv)-50
```